# Why can't I use =default for default ctors with a member initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, default-constructor, ctor-initializer

Consider the following class:

```
class Foo {
  int a, b;
public:
  Foo() : a{1}, b{2} {} // Default ctor with member initializer list
  //Foo() : a{1}, b{2} = default; // Does not work but why?
};
```

*(**Edit**: because it was mentioned in a couple of answers - I'm aware of in-class member initializiers, but that's not the point here)*

I think the second ctor definition would be more elegant and fit better into modern C++ code (see also [why you should use `=default` if you have to be explicit about using the default semantics](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-eqdefault)). However, no common compiler seems to accept it. And cppreference is silent about it.

My first thought was that a member initializer list in a way changes the "default semantics" as explained in the linked FAQ, because it may or may not default-construct members. But then we would have the same problem for in-class initializers, just that here `Foo() = default;` works just fine.

So, why is it disallowed?

Comment: As soon as you've defined initialisers in the ctor you've provided a ctor and it's no longer the default.

Comment: Because "Default ctor with member initializer list" is not a default ctor. You can use inline initialization with "=default" though.

Comment: `{}` is shorter than `=default` anyway.

Comment: @Quimby that's not an argument, since this is always the case. Also that's not the reason for `=default`, see also the referenced C++ FAQ

Comment: So what happens if you do this in a copy constructor? Would it initialize the member to the value you specified, or copy it (the default behavior)?

Comment: Could you explain what you would expect it to mean?

Comment: @Quimby, `{}` and `= default;` are different in general.

Comment: Indeed, `{}` and `=default` accomplish different things. `{}` is generally not what you want as it kills implicitly generated default move constructor/operator.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: [I don't agree](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor): _"A default constructor is a constructor which can be called with no arguments (either defined with an empty parameter list, or with default arguments provided for every parameter)."_ (unless you're talking about _defaulted_ default ctors)

Comment: @andreee two different meanings of the word "default" :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`= default;` is an entire definition all on its own. It's enforced, first and foremost, grammatically:

> **[dcl.fct.def.general]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.fct.def.general#1) Function definitions have the form
>
> ```
> function-definition:
>     attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seqopt declarator virt-specifier-seqopt function-body
>
> function-body:
>     ctor-initializeropt compound-statement
>     function-try-block
>     = default ;
>     = delete ;
> ```

So it's either a member initializer list with a compound statement, or just plain `= default;`, no mishmash.

Furthermore, `= default` means something specific about how each member is initialized. It means *we explicitly* want to initialize everything like a compiler provided constructor would. That is in contradiction to "doing something special" with the members in the constructor's member initializer list.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph: What about in-class member initializers then? defining `int a = 1; int b = 2` in the class and using `Foo() = default;` works just fine. Wouldn't that be a contradiction?

Comment: @andreee - No. Because if you omit `Foo() = default`, the default member initializers are still in effect. That *is* what the compiler provided constructor will do.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now. I also liked [@NathanOliver's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56460859/1753435) a lot, but I like this one slightly better (and you cannot accept two questions :-)).

Answer (score 7):

Doing `a{1}, b{2}` means you no longer can specify it as `default`.  A default function per [[dcl.fct.def.default]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def#default-1) is defined as

> A function definition whose *function-body* is of the form `= default;` is called an *explicitly-defaulted* definition.

And if we check what a *function-body* is in [[dcl.fct.def.general]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.def#general-1) we see that it contains a [*ctor-initializer*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init#nt:ctor-initializer) which is a [*mem-initializer-list*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.base.init#nt:mem-initializer-list)

This means you can't initialize members if you want a default definition provided by the compiler.

What you can do to work around this is to specify the default values in the class directly, and then declare the constructor as default like

```
class Foo {
  int a{1}, b{2};
public:
  Foo() = default;

};
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't directly answer the question, however it is the c++ "way" is to use the [default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members) instead, that it

```
class Foo {
  int a = 1, b = 2;
public:
  Foo() = default; 
};
```

The syntax you purpose is simply not a default, per se, constructor anymore.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in my question, this is not what I was interested in.

Answer (score 2):

It's disallowed because what you're trying to do by definition means it's no longer a default constructor. And there's a more elegant way of accomplishing what you want anyway:

```
class Foo {
  int a {1};
  int b {2};
public:
  Foo() = default;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in my question, this is not what I was interested in.

Comment: You mean, as you mentioned in an edit to your question after this answer had been posted?

Comment: Yes. But I also mentioned in-class initializers in my original post and that it doesn't pose a problem there (second last paragraph). That was just a remark, no offense :-)

Comment: a default constructor is by definition one that can be called with no arguments. see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor